# How to make a foreign key in T-SQL to null

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a tableA that have foreign key to tableB:

```
TableA (id, tableBId, attributeA)
```

Now I want to insert a row into `tableA` but set the `tableBId` to `NULL` because at that time, I cannot determine it.

Here is my sql query :

```
insert into TableA values (tableId, attributeA)
```

`tableId` I have set to 0 or -1, but always receive an error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY

I understand this error, because 0 and -1 doesn't belong to any id of `TableB`. So, my question is : how can I set null to `tableBId` in this case?

Comment: is `tableBId` nullable?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't really understand this. can you tell me more please. tableBId is an int. and if I makes it type `int?`, I cannot put into object. thanks :)

Comment: Just how do you expect to insert a null but if the .NET variable  tableID cannot be null?

Comment: why tableID cannot be null ? I think simply we put it null. as a post below that recommend me using DBNull.Value, but this type does not comparable with any system type. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Use logic in .NET to pass 'dbnull' if the value is null

Comment: @hqt would be helpful to see the `c#` code you are using to assign your values to the variable `tableId`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set the tableBId column to accept nulls
2. On the C# side, pass DbNull.Value for tableId value, instead of 0 or -1

**edit**

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TableA (tableId, attributeA) values (@tableId, @attributeA)";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableId", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@tableId"].Value = tableId > 0 ? tableId : (object)DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@attributeA", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@attributeA"].Value = tableId;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: How can I represent this into object. because before I put into database, I create object for it first. and DbNull is not comparable to any system type. thanks :)

Comment: thanks for your great answer. just another two sub-questions : when I retrieve again data from database, I must use if structure like above ? and second, Here the way I use : `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableId", tableId > 0 ? tableId : (object)DBNull.Value);` any difference with you ? thanks :)

Comment: (1) Yes, on retrieval, if the column supports nulls, then you should be testing for DbNull values. You can use the C# helper function `Convert.IsDBNull()` to test for nulls. (2) The `AddWithValue` method doesn't support declaring the parameter type. I find it's more robust to declare the parameter type [check here for more information](http://forums.asp.net/t/1200255.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tableId column in the designer to Allow Nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly name the columns in your destination table, like so:

```
 insert into TableA (id, attributeA) values (tableId, attributeA)
```

Answer (score 0):

your should send the following instruction to your database:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ALTER COLUMN tableBId bit null
```

this will allow null values to be stored in your `tableBId` field. Default value for newly created records will be Null.

If this script returns an error related to your foreign key, you'll then have to drop the foreign key constraint before running this script. In this case just

drop the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT myConstraintName
```

run the script (see before)

reset the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraintName foreign key(tableBId) references tableB(id)
```